# Curl method with authentification problem

Tags: bash, shell, azure

I have a little problem with my bearer:

I have a config file with my variable bearer like this:

- bearer = "*********"

And I have my script test.sh :

```
source /home/name/test/config


curl -X GET \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer $bearer' \https://.../api/vendors \-o 
 json_file/vendors.json
```

And then when I open my file vendors.json. It say token invalid or was expired and normaly my token is good, I'm sure. So Where is my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the right token? The server seems to believe the token you are sending is invalid. They often come with expiration dates and times, sometimes quite short.

Comment: Hmm ok I try again .. Normaly I have the good token

Comment: Same problem with the good token

Comment: I suppose it's not a "good token" after all. Which API are you using? Does it use OAuth? A lot of APIs require some form of authorization call to generate a token using your API key and API secret. You are probably missing that step

Comment: Ok I understand. But when I put the token directly in my script like this : -H 'Authorization: Bearer *****' it works ! Now I'm trying to do the same thing with a variable ...

Comment: Where does the variable come from? I don't see it getting assigned anywhere in this script

Comment: I'm doing export bearer=$bearer, I forget to ad in my script. But have always same problem